# Put a default event between two dates

Tags: php, datetime

I have to get a list of events everyday like this :

```
$data = getEvents();
$content='';
foreach($data as $d)
{
    $content.= $d['date'].' '.$d['ID_Event']."<br />";
}
echo $content;
-------> 
2015-03-20 1
2015-03-22 2
2015-03-23 3
```

I have to check if in this list, i have an empty day between each two dates, and put a default event with id = 4 so i have this result

```
  2015-03-20 1
**2015-03-21 4**
  2015-03-22 2
  2015-03-23 3
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, i tried to calculate the number of days between two dates, using diff() function, but i didn't get any result.

Comment: ^ Even if it doesn't work add your attempt(s) to your question! (Also if you have 2 empty days between 2 events do you have to put 2x id4 in between ?)

Comment: if i have tow or more empty days, i have to put the date of the day + id4, so i  can have at least a list with no empty day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = getEvents();
$default = 4;
$content='';
foreach($data as $index=>$d)
{
    $date = new DateTime($d['date']);
    $content.= $d['date'].' '.$d['ID_Event']."<br />";

    //check if we have a next event
    if (isset($data[$index+1])){
        //get the date of next event
        $next = new DateTime($data[$index+1]['date']);
        //how many days till next event
        $difference = $date->diff($next)->d;
        //more then 1 day in between two events
        if($difference > 1){
            //loop through each day difference
            for($i = 2; $i <= $difference; $i++){
                //take the last even date and add one day to it
                $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
                //add the new date to content with your default event
                $content.= $date->format('Y-m-d').' '.$default."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $content;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but what will be the default event ? 
like this ?? $content .= $data[$index]['date']." 4<br />";
that's doesn't work

Comment: Since I have no test data I could not test it. But this should be pretty much everything what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Here I first sort the `$data` array by the date with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) after this I create a [`new DatePeriod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php) for all dates between the start and the end. The I just simple loop through all dates and if it is in the `$data` array I add it to the `$output` array otherwise I make an element with the EventID 4. And at the end I just simply print the data)

```
<?php

    $data = getEvents();
    usort($data, function($a, $b){
        return strtotime($a["date"]) > strtotime($b["date"]);
    });

    $start = new DateTime($data[0]["date"]);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $end = (new DateTime($data[count($data)-1]["date"]))->add($interval);

    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach($period as $date) {
        if(($key = array_search($date->format("Y-m-d"), array_column($data, "date"))) !== FALSE)
            $content[] = $data[$key];
        else
            $content[] = ["date" => $date->format("Y-m-d"), "ID_Event" => "4"];
    }

    array_map(function($v){
        echo $v['date'] . " " . $v['ID_Event'] . "<br />";
    }, $content);

?>
```